# constructing a probability measure which is absolutely continous

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

$X$ be a Polish space and $\mu, \nu$ be two any probability measure on it. Could anyone tell me how to construct a $\sigma$-finite probability measure $\lambda$ such that $\mu\ll \lambda$ and $\nu\ll \lambda$. Thanks!

Comment: Probability measures are finite by definition (hence also $\sigma$-finite). So the condition on $\lambda$ is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take $\lambda =(\mu +\nu) /2$.

Comment: @GabrielRomon OP is talking about sigma finite probability measure! That sounds strange. I think he just means sigma finite measure. Anyway I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for $\lambda=\frac12\mu+\frac12\nu$.