# total variation distance in terms of Hahn decomposition

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

with notations as previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3350581/constructing-a-probability-measure-which-is-absolutely-continous/3350582#3350582). Consider any two $X$ valued random variable $\eta_1$ and $\eta_2$ such that  $\eta_1\sim \mu$ and $\eta_2\sim \nu$. Let $X=A^+\cup A^-$ be the Hahn decomposition of $\mu-\nu$. then

$\|\mu-\nu\|_{TV}=2(\mu(A^+)- \nu(A^+))$ (I don't understand how, could any one explain me a bit)

and $\|\mu-\nu\|_{TV}=2(\mu(A^+)- \nu(A^+))= 2\mathbb E(I_{\eta_1\in A^+}- I_{\eta_2\in A^+})= $, also quet not clear how.

Thanks!

I know that Hahn decomposition says for any signed measure $m$, there exists unique sets $P$ and $N$ such that $X=P\cup N$ with the fact that $m(A)\ge 0\forall A\subseteq P$ and $m(A)\le 0\forall A\subseteq N$.

Comment: Something seems wrong in the first equality you say you don't understand. If $\mu = \nu \neq 0$ then any decomposition of $X$ is a Hahn-decomposition for $\mu - \nu = 0$ so we can suppose $A^+ = X, A^- = \emptyset$. Then $\|\mu - \nu\|_{TV} = 0$ but $\mu(A^+) - \nu(A^-) = \mu(X) > 0$.

Comment: Oops, i have edited it now.

Comment: This still isn't right. Consider the case $\mu = 0$, $\nu \neq 0$. Then $A^+ = \emptyset$ but $\|\mu - \nu\|_{TV} \neq 0$. Do you mean to write $\|\mu - \nu\|_{TV} = 2(\lambda(A^+) - \lambda(A^-))$ where $\lambda = \mu - \nu$? If so, you might be interested in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3287983/256128) as related material; it proves that result by an indirect route but also contains the ideas you'd need to make a direct argument.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it.